# Hive, create table ___ like ___ stored as ___

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a table in hive stored as text files. I want to move all the data into another table with the same schema but stored as sequence files. 
How do I create the second table? I wanted to use the hive `create table like` command but it doesn't support `as sequencefile`

```
hive> create table test_sq like test_t stored as sequencefile;
FAILED: ParseException line 1:33 missing EOF at 'stored' near 'test_t'
```

I am looking for a programmatic way so that I can replicate the same process for more tables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE test_t LIKE test_sq;
```

It just copies the source table definition.The new table contains no rows. As you said you have to move all the data. In this case above query is not suitable;

try this,

```
CREATE TABLE test_sq row format delimited fields terminated by '|' STORED AS sequencefile AS select * from test_t;
```

- Target cannot be partitioned table.
- Target cannot be external table.
- It copies the structure as well as the data

Note - if you don't want to give row format delimited then remove from query. You can give where clause also in query to copy selected rows;

Comment: Not surprisingly, it ran a hadoop job to perform the task. Worked as expected :)

Comment: What do you mean by Target cannot be partitioned table? test_sq cannot be partitioned or test_t cannot be partitioned?

Comment: mean the table which you want to create should not have partitioned. check this https://dzone.com/articles/introduction-hives

Answer (score 0):

Try using create + insert together.

Use the normal DDL statement to create the table.

```
CREATE TABLE test2 (a INT) STORED AS SEQUENCEFILE
```

then use

```
INSERT INTO test2 AS SELECT * FROM test;
```

test is the table with Textfile as data format and 'test2' is the table with SEQUENCEFILE data format.

Comment: That's what I said I don't want to do. I am looking for a programmatic way, so that I don't have to write CREATE TABLE statements with its whole schema. Because this cannot be replicated over say 1000 tables